# Invariant operator against shift/scale: Is there a general form for an operator $D$ such that $D\phi = D\alpha\phi + b$, for $a>0$, $b$ real?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\Phi$ be the set of strictly increasing differentiable functions from $(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ that diverge to minus infinity as the argument goes to 0. In other words:

$$\Phi := \{ \phi : (0,1)\to \mathbb{R} \text{ continuously diff } \mid \phi'>0, \lim_{x\to 0} \phi(x) = -\infty \} $$

I'm looking for a general form of operators $D:\Phi \to \Phi$ of functions that are invariant to positive scaling and translations of $\phi$, that is $D\phi = D(a\phi + b)$, for $a>0$ and $b$ real.

It's not hard to find some examples:

1. $D_1\phi = \frac{\phi(w) - \phi(c)}{\phi'(c)}$ for $c\in(0,1)$
2. $D_2\phi = \frac{\phi(w) - \phi(c_1)}{\phi(c_2)-\phi(c_1)}$, for $c1 < c2 \in (0,1)$

My question is whether there is a general form for these.

I don't know if this question is too broad or too simple,so I'd appreciate any suggestions as well.

Comment: By $[0,1]$ do you mean $(0,1)$? If not, your $\Phi$ is empty because $\phi(0)>-\infty$. Also note that increasing does not imply continuous or differentiable.

Comment: Yes, I mean (0,1) and continuously differentiable. I edited the question to consider what you said. Thanks!